# PHP Number Format - Aligning Numbers with Brackets

Tags: php

I'm using  the following function to turn my numbers into 2 decimals with negatives in parenthesis.This almost works

However as I have them right aligned they don't quite line up as i'd like.

The ) sits above the 3. It would be better if the 4 and 3 aligned above each other.

```
 (11,870.74)
    2,806.33
```

Is any of this possible?

```
function myformat($nr)
{
    $nr = number_format($nr, 2);
    return $nr[0] == '-' ?  "(" . substr($nr, 1) . ")" : $nr;
}
```

Comment: You don't show the code that aligns the numbers.

Comment: Not really related to your issue directly -- but isn't it traditional to use either the negative sign or the parens, and not both? (Been a while since I've written accounting reports...)

Comment: That's why he has `substr($nr, 1)` in his function.

Comment: That's a rather misleading sample output then, inn't it? :)

Comment: output changed in sample for any future references to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space at the end of the positive number, to match the close parenthesis:

```
function myformat($nr)
{
    $nr = number_format($nr, 2);
    return $nr[0] == '-' ?  "(" . substr($nr, 1) . ")" : $nr . ' ';
}
```

I assume you're using `printf()` in the caller to right-align the results.